# C++ Struct in array, help!

Tags: c++, iphone, objective-c, arrays, struct

I have an iPhone app that used to use an array of several thousand small objects for its data source. Now, I am trying to make it use C++ Structs, to improve performance. I have written the struct, and put it in "Particle.h":

```
typedef struct{
   double changeX;
   double changeY;
   double x;
   double y;
}ParticleStruct;
```

Then, I imported "Particle.h", and attempted to define the array:

```
#import "Particle.h"
@implementation ParticleDisplay
struct ParticleStruct particles[];   
///Size will be determined later, this declaration is to make 
 ////the declaration visible to the entire class...
```

On this line, however, I get the error: "Array type has incomplete element type".
Everything else compiles fine, as far as I can tell, and I am sure that "Particle.h" has been imported before the declaration.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have already `typedef`ed it in Particle.h, drop the word `struct` from the array declaration line (the line where the error is).

HOWEVER,

- In C++, you do not need to `typedef` it, just write `struct Particle { /* members */ };`
- Why are you declaring an array without the length? Consider using `std::vector` ([tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/vector/)) which is a *dynamically* re-sizeable array (you don't have to bother about the length ever). It is simple as: `std::vector< Particle > particles;`

Comment: I tried to use the vector, but  #include <vector> throws an error, says no such file or directory.

Comment: @Chris: Hmm.. then it is something with the (iphone) development environment. I have no clue on that. Sorry.

Comment: change your implementation file type to sourcecode.cpp.objcpp then your #include<vector> should work ( include in implementation file not header ).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, in c++ you don't need to typedef your structs. You don't need to use the struct keyword to declare a variable with some struct type:

```
 ParticleStruct *particles;
```

Use a pointer (as above) for your variable. Then you can dynamically allocate memory for it. Or better yet, use a [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/vector/):

```
vector<ParticleStruct> particles;
```

It seems that you need to familiarize yourself with c++. Consider reading [a book or two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Ya, i've been considering learning the language outright, but I rarely use C++ in iPhone development, and when I need to I can usually scrape by with help from the internet... Maybe when I get a break from school...

Comment: @Chris: also, don't assume that c++ is more efficient that c. It can be, but if you don't know the language, you'll just expend a bunch of time and probably come out behind trying to re implement some c code.